# How to create separate dataframes from a list of data frames? eg df1 = df[0]

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of dataframes (it's just how I inherited them from an import) How do I write a loop to create individual dataframes from list of dataframes?
Rather than doing it manually like this?

```
df1 = df[0] 
df2 = df[1] 
df3 = df[2] 
df4 = df[3] 
df5 = df[4] 
df6 = df[5]
```

I'm so dusty

```
counter = 0
n = counter+1

for i in range(0,len(df)-1):
  if counter==0:
    dfn = df[counter]
```

Comment: Why is there a problem in using it directly? Why do you need to assign it to a new variable?

Comment: what you have is this: list = [ df1[0], df[1], df[3]...]  ??

Answer (score 0):

```
df = [-1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6]

for i in range(0, len(df)):
    globals()[f'df{i + 1}'] = df[i]

print(f'df1 = {df1}')
print(f'df2 = {df2}')
print(f'df3 = {df3}')
print(f'df4 = {df4}')
print(f'df5 = {df5}')
print(f'df6 = {df6}')
```

in console

```
df1 = -1
df2 = -2
df3 = -3
df4 = -4
df5 = -5
df6 = -6
```